# How to show return data from vue apollo within a <script setup> syntax

Tags: api, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-apollo

I followed this tutorial in Vue Apollo for retrieving data with fake api https://www.apollographql.com/blog/frontend/getting-started-with-vue-apollo/.

I however have a code where I use `<script setup></script>` instead of the usual `setup()` method where everything there is placed.

How should I return data on my elements in this instance?

So this is currently my vue file:

```js
<script setup>
    import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia';
    import { useAuthStore, useUsersStore } from '@/stores';

    import gql from 'graphql-tag'
    import { useQuery } from '@vue/apollo-composable'

    const authStore = useAuthStore();
    const { user: authUser } = storeToRefs(authStore);

    const usersStore = useUsersStore();
    const { users } = storeToRefs(usersStore);

    usersStore.getAll();

    apollo: gql`
        query Characters {
            characters {
            results {
                id
                name
                image
            }
        }
    }
    `
    const { result, loading, error } = useQuery(CHARACTERS_QUERY);
}
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Hi {{authUser?.firstName}}!</h1>
        <div v-if="users.loading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm"></div>
        <div v-if="users.error" class="text-danger">Error loading users: {{users.error}}</div>
        <p v-if="error">Something went wrong...</p>
        <p v-if="loading">Loading...</p>
        <p v-else v-for="character in result.characters.results" :key="character.id">
            {{ character.name }}
        </p>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Then my main.js is:

```js
import { createApp, provide, h } from 'vue';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';

import App from './App.vue';
import { router } from './helpers';

// setup fake backend
import { fakeBackend } from './helpers';
fakeBackend();

import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client/core'
import { DefaultApolloClient } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import { createApolloProvider } from '@vue/apollo-option'

const cache = new InMemoryCache()

const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  uri: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/graphql',
})

const apolloProvider = createApolloProvider({
  defaultClient: apolloClient,
})

const app = createApp({
  setup () {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient)
  },
  render: () => h(App),
})

app.use(apolloProvider)

app.use(createPinia());
app.use(router);

app.mount('#app');
```

With the `<script setup></script>` it is showing this error?

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrkbn.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you made mistake during copypasting.

Replace this:

```js
    apollo: gql`
        query Characters {
            characters {
            results {
                id
                name
                image
            }
        }
    }
    `
```

With this:

```js
const CHARACTERS_QUERY = gql`
        query Characters {
            characters {
            results {
                id
                name
                image
            }
        }
    }
    `
```

Comment: Thanks! I still got the Unexpected Error though.

Comment: Can you provide more info about error?

Comment: Please see this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrkbn.jpg

Comment: But this is screenshot with old error. Error must be gone after fix. Did you reload dev server after changes?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is still the same error: https://i.ibb.co/rMgLz1y/Screen-Shot-2022-08-24-at-7-29-33-AM.png

Comment: Oh it's working now. There was a just an extra "}". Thank you for the help